# Assign an empty array to an object which implements interface and push new objects into it later on

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface FacilityInformation
{
  facilitiesInformation: [
  {
    id: string,
    productType: string,
    productSubtype: string,
    nominalAmount: number,
    currency: string,
    maturity: string,
    fee: number,
    recommended: number,
    margin: number,
    roac: number,
    ep: number
  }
 ],
 allFacilities: {
  amount: number,
  fee: number,
  roac: number,
  ep: number
 },
 customerLevel: {
  amount: number,
  fee: number,
  roac: number,
  ep: number
 },
 groupLevel: {
  amount: number,
  fee: number,
  roac: number,
  ep: number
 }
}
```

My goal is to initialize an empty object which implements interface `FacilityInformation` with an EMPTY array `facilitiesInformation` and later push objects into this array. However, I can't seem to be able to initialize an empty array, it asks me to assign values straight away:

```
let facilityInformation : FacilityInformation = 
{
  facilitiesInformation :   
  { id: string, productType: string ... } [], // says string is a type but used as a value
```

After assigning an empty array I would like to do this:

```
  facilityInformation.facilitiesInformation.push({...})
```

How can I first if all initialize an empty array and then push objects into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way.

```
let facilityInformation: FacilityInformation = 
{
  facilitiesInformation: [] as any,
  ...
} as FacilityInformation;
```

Comment: I get an error: Property '0' is missing in type '[]' but required in type '[{ id: string, productType: string ... }]'

Comment: I get an error: Types of property facilitiesInformation are incompatible.

Comment: Try edited answer again please: See this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkjl4p